# Twilio PHP SDK - Did twilio receive my request?

Tags: twilio

We are using the Twilio PHP SDK and the Notify Client.  When I make a request how do I get the status of that request.  Did it return a good 2XX, an error 4XX?  And to be clear, I don't mean, what is the status of the messages.  I simply mean, did twilio get my API call?

When testing in Postman with the REST API I typically get a 200 or 201 response if everything went well.

```
$twilio = new Client($acct_sid, $token);

$Addresses = array("+12015551234");
$toBindingAttributes = array();

foreach ($Addresses as $Address) {
    array_push($toBindingAttributes, '{"binding_type":"sms","address":"' . $Address . '"}');
}

$notification = $twilio->notify->services($notify_sid)
                                   ->notifications->create([
      "toBinding" => $toBindingAttributes,
      "body" => "Twilio Test."
     ]);
```

I've tried to return $notification and I just get `[Twilio.Notify.V1.NotificationInstance]`

-----**Edit**-----

ok I realize now that `[Twilio.Notify.V1.NotificationInstance]` is an object. I was able to `print_r($notification)` and see that there is a statusCode property.

I tried to echo that property `print_r(@notification->statusCode)` but I get "Unknown Property".

Is it because it's "protected"?
`[statusCode:protected] => 201`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the result is the `[Twilio.Notify.V1.NotificationInstance]` object.
The problem is all the properties within the object are protected we cannot access them directly.

We were able to get to them with a bunch of strpos, substr, and regex but found a much easier way using a getter.

By doing this way 
`print($twilio->getHttpClient()->lastResponse->getStatusCode());`

More info in the Twilio-PHP library

https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/650f42647c9b3039e03ae075785164ec97203e94/src/Twilio/Http/Response.php